# What property keyword should I use for a setter that stores the value in a collection class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone

I was quickly going over a large project looking for memory leaks, and came across a `@property (nonatomic, retain)` without a corresponding `release` in `dealloc`.  Oops, quick fix, I think.

After a later crash, I look closer and the `setFoo` method is overriden, and the value is being retained but not by the ivar - for the sake of this question, assume it's being put into an NSDictionary.

(OK, if you don't want to assume that - the set value is actually a CCSprite in cocos2d, `setNormalSprite`,  and it is being added as a child, thus retained, but simply assigned to the ivar:

```
 - (void)setNormalSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite 
  {
    if (normalSprite) {
        [self removeChild:normalSprite cleanup:YES];
        normalSprite = nil;
    }

    normalSprite = sprite;
    [self addChild:normalSprite];

    (...omitted...)
   }
```

)

What is the correct keyword for a value whose setter causes the retain count to increase, but not because the ivar it's associated with is retained?

Comment: If you pass the same sprite as normalSprite, that setter may crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`retain` (or `strong` in ARC world) is correct in your case because you're adding your `CSSprite` object into another collection that retains the object.

You should set the `@property` to `@dynamic` in your `@implementation` too if you are not actually using an instance variable to store the object.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using ARC and you are explicitly writing the setter method, then it doesn't matter what ownership attribute you use. The ownership attribute only matters if the compiler generates the setter or (under ARC) the ivar.

You can use the retain attribute as documentation that the object takes ownership of the property value, but it's up to you to make sure that you actually do retain it somehow.

Comment: That's a good point, I should have perhaps put "correct" in quotes.  I realize the behavior will not change but am wondering if there is a consensus that one keyword or the other is more appropriate - for readability, or convention or ... some other thing.